# PySpark - accidentally overwritten the Downloads folder, any ways to recover the data?

Tags: python, pyspark, recover

While trying to write a file on to the Downloads folder using the command -
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
interaction_level_df.write.mode('overwrite').parquet("/Users/joe/Downloads/")

It deleted all the existing files and folders from the Downloads folder.
Is there any way to recover the lost data?
I am on a macbook and the time machine is not enabled. Thank you

I tried a third party software with no luck